# Weak topology induced by a separating set of functions that are continuous on a compact space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm having trouble with this problem and would like some help -

> Let $X$ be a *compact* topological space.
>
> Let $F$ be a separating set of *continuous* functions $X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Show that the weak topology induced by $F$ is the same as the original topology on $X$.

I can show that $X$ is $T_4$ and that every $f\in F$ is closed, but I'm not sure how to use it further.

Comment: The initial topology is also considered wrt $F$?

Comment: @FShrike yes, the functions in $F$ are continuous with respect to the initial topology of $X$

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. "Initial topology" needs to have more context to it, in order to be defined. We need a family of functions with which to define initial topology. I asked if you considered $F$ as this family

Comment: Or maybe it's also possible that instead of "initial" as a term, OP meant the *original* topology that came with X in the first place?

Comment: Looks like an exercise on Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: @FShrike yes, F is this family. I wasn't aware that initial and original have different meanings, I edited the question

Comment: I just realised that the op probably means by "weak topology" what I thought they meant by "initial topology" so my question is redundant anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the weak topology induced from $F$ is refined by the topology on $X$. Therefore it suffices to show that if $U\subseteq X$ is open then it is also weakly open.

Fix any $x\in U$. We want to find finitely many $f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_n\in F$ and finitely many open $V_1,V_2,\cdots,V_n\subseteq\Bbb R$ with $x\in\bigcap_{j=1}^nf_j^{-1}(V_j)\subseteq U$.

My hint to you is to mimic the proof that compact sets are closed, in a Hausdorff space. Think about how we even know $X$ is Hausdorff.

> $K:=X\setminus U$ is closed hence compact. Assume $U$ is a proper subset of $X$, for else the question is trivial. For any $y\in K$, choose $g_y\in F$ which separates $x$ from $y$.

> There are disjoint open neighbourhoods $V_y$ of $g_y(x)$ and $W_y$ of $g_y(y)$; by compactness there are finitely many $\{y_j:j=1,\cdots,n\}\subseteq K$ with $K\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^ng_{y_j}^{-1}(W_{y_j}):=W$.

> It is clear that: $$x\in\bigcap_{j=1}^ng_{y_j}^{-1}(V_{y_j})\subseteq X\setminus W\subseteq U$$As desired.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

Let $\tau$ be the original topology, and $\omega$ the weak topology induced by $F$.  It is clear by definition of weak topology that $\omega \subseteq \tau$.  We have to show the reverse.

1. Use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to show that every $\tau$-continuous $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is also $\omega$-continuous.
2. Let $U$ be a $\tau$-open set and $x \in U$.  Use Urysohn's lemma to produce a $\tau$-continuous $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = 1$ and $f = 0$ outside $U$.  (Note the existence of a separating set implied that $\tau$ was Hausdorff.)  Since $f$ is also $\omega$-continuous, the set $V = \{f > 1/2\}$ is $\omega$-open and $x \in V \subseteq U$.  Since $x \in U$ was arbitrary, conclude that $U$ is $\omega$-open.